# extract and remove substring from a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string as below

```
"/br/watch/123456"
```

I need to remove /br and extract only /watch/123456. what is the best way to achieve it in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) to remove first occurrence of `/br` from string, else [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to remove all occurrences

```
"/br/watch/123456".sub("/br","")
# => "/watch/123456"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sub. `sub` helps to do a single replacement on strings. The below code will remove the `/br` sub-string only if it's present at the start.

```
> "/br/watch/123456".sub(/^\/br/, '')
=> "/watch/123456"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always three characters that should be removed you can.

```
"/br/watch/123456"[3..-1]
```

or more verbose and probably slower

```
"/br/watch/123456".chars.drop(3).join
```